# how to get the timetamp for the linux kernel?

Tags: c, linux, pointers, linux-kernel, timestamp

```
int netif_rx(struct sk_buff *skb) 
{
if(skb -> stamp.tv_sec ==0)
do_gettimeofday(&skb->stamp);
}
```

the above api is the receiver side api, which receives the data from the sender. I want to calculate t
he time when it receives the data and store it in a buffer.
the above api at line number 2993 is available in kernel source code at: /linux/net/core/dev.c
but I am getting ERROR: as struct sk_buff has no member named stamp.

http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/include/linux/skbuff.h
Could someone please help me : how to get the timestamp for linux kernel.

Later I changed my code to :

```
 int netif_rx(struct sk_buff *skb) 
    {
    if(skb -> tstamp.off_sec ==0)
    do_gettimeofday(&skb->tstamp);
    }
```

now I am getting error as : ktime_t has no memeber named "tv_sec". struct timeval but argument is of type unio ktime_t.

Answer (score 0):

`sk_buff->tstamp` is variable of `ktime_t` type. `do_gettimeofday` sets time to variable of `struct timeval`. You have different types here and so you need a conversion. A simple one would be:

```
int netif_rx(struct sk_buff *skb) 
{
    if(skb -> tstamp.off_sec ==0)
    {
        struct timespec now;
        getnstimeofday(&now);
        skb->tstamp = timespec_to_ktime(now);
    }
}
```

Answer (score -3):

Try to use `tstamp` instead of `stamp`.

Comment: The structure path would be more like:    skb->tstamp.tv.sec