# timestamp error in linux kernel?

Tags: c, linux, struct, linux-kernel, timestamp

```
int netif_rx(struct sk_buff *skb) 
{
if(skb -> stamp.tv_sec ==0)
do_gettimeofday(&skb->stamp);
}
```

the above api is the receiver side api, which receives the data from the sender. I want to calculate t he time when it receives the data and store it in a buffer. the above api at line number 2993 is available in kernel source code at: /linux/net/core/dev.c
but I am getting ERROR: as struct sk_buff has no member named stamp.

http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/include/linux/skbuff.h Could someone please help me : how to get the timestamp for linux kernel.

Later I changed my code to :

```
 int netif_rx(struct sk_buff *skb) 
    {
    if(skb -> tstamp.off_sec ==0)
    do_gettimeofday(&skb->tstamp);
    }
```

1 : http://www.fsl.cs.sunysb.edu/kernel-api/re498.html

---

2 : https://github.com/embest-tech/platform_prebuilt/blob/master/ndk/android-ndk-r7/platforms/android-4/arch-x86/usr/include/linux/skbuff.h

-------------------------check this at line 81----------------------------------------------

now I am getting error as : ktime_t has no memeber named "tv_sec". struct timeval but argument is of type unio ktime_t.

Comment: I think you asked similar question before http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22994045/how-to-get-the-timetamp-for-the-linux-kernel

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`sk_buff->tstamp` is variable of `ktime_t` type. `do_gettimeofday` sets time to variable of `struct timeval`. You have different types here and so you need a conversion. A simple one would be:

```
int netif_rx(struct sk_buff *skb) 
{
    if(skb -> tstamp.off_sec ==0)
    {
        struct timespec now;
        getnstimeofday(&now);
        skb->tstamp = timespec_to_ktime(now);
    }
}
```

**Edit:**
If you just want to timestamp socket buffer you can call [`__net_timestamp`](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/include/linux/skbuff.h?v=3.2#L2181)

```
int netif_rx(struct sk_buff *skb) 
{
    __net_timestamp(skb);
}
```

Or if you can't call `__net_timestamp` you can do it by your hands:

```
int netif_rx(struct sk_buff *skb) 
{
    skb->tstamp = ktime_get_real();
}
```

Comment: I am getting error as : ktime_t has no member named off_sec.

Comment: Where the hell did you find that `if(skb -> tstamp.off_sec ==0)` condition? What do you want to check for? If you want to check for unset time use `tstamp.tv.sec`.

Comment: I dont want to check the if condition but I want to calculate the time when the data as arrived on the device driver. The function for the device driver is netif_rx and want to calculate the time inside and store in the buffer.

Comment: What kernel are you using? What distro? Is it Android?

Comment: I am using Linux RTPC 3.2.48-rt69-2. I want to get the timestamp of the data arrival and store it in a buffer. it is real time linux operating system.

Comment: the both answers you update will finally store the timestamp in socket buffer ?? what about the answer updated above by user user3137338 ??  which one is correct ??

Comment: I am able to call __net_timestamp(skb); then finally I will get the timestamp and the solution will be stored in skb buffer. is it right ??  where is the function definition for ktime_get_real(); and  __net_timestamp(skb); ??  I founf ktime_get_real - get the real (wall-) time in ktime_t format.

Comment: Come on, can you google by yourself? ktime_get_real is in <linux/hrtimer.h> and __net_timestamp is in <linux/skbuff.h>

Comment: thank you very much and my last question is : skb->tstamp = ktime_get_real();  //the timestamp will be stored in skb buffer . is it right ??

Comment: Yes, but why won't you try by yourself?

Comment: HI!! how to use this timestamp of the kernel on the user space (I ma using recvfrom api for udp)?? how to acces the kernel memory from recvfrom api on user side ??

Comment: I want to read the timestamp packet from user space which is stored in the memory of kernel.

Comment: Please, don't make off-topic discussion here - ask a new question.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23061469/how-to-access-the-kernel-memory-from-user-program-in-rt-linux    Could you please answer for that ??

Comment: extern double interrupt time; 
int netif_rx(struct sk_buff *skb) 
{
     interrupt tiem = ktime_get_real();
}   // if I do like this anywhere inside the kernel. I will get a timstamp. Isnt it ?? so that I can use this variable for sending it to the user program via pocfs . is this right ??

Answer (score 0):

You can do it this way

```
your_function(struct sk_buff *skb)
{
    struct timeval tv;

    do_gettimeofday(&tv);
    skb->tstamp = timeval_to_ktime(tv);
}
```

[Have a look at this code](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/drivers/net/wireless/mwifiex/main.c#L660)
`mwifiex_hard_start_xmit` function

On a side-note in most of the cases , you do not need to provide your own implementation of `netif_rx`

Comment: I want to calculate the time when the data as arrived on the device driver. The function for the device driver is netif_rx and want to calculate the time inside.

Comment: @avd has mentioned it all what is necessary.