# how to access the kernel memory from user program in rt linux?

Tags: c, linux, sockets, linux-kernel, timestamp

client and server communication in rt linux. client is sending the data and server is the receiver.UDP is used for communication between client and the server.
When the server(rt linux) receives the data from the client the kernel should stop what it is doing and start executing the newly arrived data. I want to calculate the time when the interrupt occurs in kernel (timestamp). 
In rt-linux all the operating system operation takes place in kernel. So i am calculating the interrupt time in kernel source code. So i modified the kernel source code in the location /usr/src/linux-version/net/core/dev.c  as shown below :
I am calculating the time and storing in a buffer skb.

//this code is at network device driver level.

```
int netif_rx(struct sk_buff *skb) 
{
    __net_timestamp(skb);//I modify the code in kernel to get the timestamp and store in buffer
}
```

// after storing the data to the buffer. kernel will send it to the upper layers like IP, UDP, INET and finally SOCKET of the kernel space.

but I want to read the timestamp packet from the kernel space by the user space. i.e. my program .

I am using recvfrom api to read the data from kernel spacce (which is in kernel memory)

QUESTION : could someone tell me how to access the kernel memory which contains the timestamp data by the user program ??

Comment: User programs should access kernel memory only thru *syscalls*

Comment: I am using recvfrom api then is it possible to recieve the data from the kernel memory ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't access kernel memory from userspace directly - you have to use some sort of API.

You can:

- Export timestamp through sysfs or debugfs and read it as regular file
- Add syscall so kernel will return current timestamp value
- Bunch of other crazy variants like netlink socket or shared memory

Comment: thank you very much. server(kernel) receives the data from the client. I am calculating the timestamp and adding it in a buffer. later it will transfer to higher levels from network device drivers to ip , udp, INET and finally socket in the kernel space (these tasks will taken care by kernel). I am the user as to receive the timestamp packet from the kernel, so I will use recvfrom api to receive the timestamp packet. Isnt it right ?? I dont want to use ftrace for kernel debugging and store the timestamp in a file. Later reading or analyzing in the offline. I want to make it online.

Comment: I don't understand you, especially this part: "I am the user as to receive the timestamp packet from kernel, so I will use recvfrom api to receive the timestamp packet".

Comment: sorry. Calculating a timestamp in kernel space and later user space as to receive (recvfrom api) the timestamp packet from kernel space and sending that packet back to the client.

Comment: where should I add syscall for the kernel to return the current timestamp value ?? could you please give more information ??

Comment: Sorry, I've never done this, but I think there are plenty of manuals on Internet.

Comment: shall i use sysfs ??  which is best in my case ?

Comment: IMHO it's easiest variant.