# calculating a timestamp in network device driver level of kernel?

Tags: c, linux, linux-kernel, kernel

```
extern double interrupt time; 
int netif_rx(struct sk_buff *skb) 
{
     skb->timestamp = ktime_get_real();
     interrupt time = skb -> timestamp; 
}
```

if I do like above in the kernel side of the program. I will get a timestamp. Isnt it ?? so that I can use the (interrupt time) variable for sending it to the user program via procfs . 
is this right ??

Comment: I want the timestamp when the kernel receives a interrupt and the above api is an network device driver level api. so ktime_get_real will give the timestamp. cant i store it in a double variable ??

Comment: else can I modify like above ??

Comment: I suggest [you check what `ktime_t` is](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/include/linux/ktime.h#L46), because your above code doesn't make much sense based on what I see.

Comment: http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/include/linux/skbuff.h?v=3.2#L2181   Could you please see this once ??  I am doing ktime_get_real !! is both are same ??

Comment: I just need a timestamp and dont want the time of a day : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23003449/timestamp-error-in-linux-kernel?lq=1   . am I right ??